# Trying to use json_decode in order to get data

Tags: php, arrays, json

They gave me this json array and i was asked to use `json_decode` in order to use the data for other purposes.

```
 $json = { "rows":[
 { id:0, data:[ "DLD224364", "13", "10.16.162.169", "4", "το ...", "2022-10-05 21:18:21" ] },
 { id:1, data:[ "DLD22364", "13", "10.16.162.164", "4", "το ...", "2022-10-05 21:17:47" ] },
 { id:2, data:[ "DLD224367", "67", "10.16.162.164", "4", "το ...", "2022-10-05 20:47:55" ] },
 { id:3, data:[ "DLD224335", "22", "10.16.162.169", "4", "το ...", "2022-10-05 20:36:03" ] },
 { id:4, data:[ "DLD224329", "38", ".162.169", "4", "το ...", "2022-10-05 20:26:55" ] },
 { id:5, data:[ "DLD024285", "58", "", "4", "το ...", "2022-10-05 17:41:08" ] },
 ] }] };
```

But when i am trying `var_dump(json_decode($json, true));`
I am getting NULL as the result..
Why is this happening ?

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid JSON array. For example, have an extra } and ] at the end of your JSON array. Try using an online validator [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) for example to ensure the JSON string is valid before you try working with it in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the error that's leading to `null` being returned, use [`json_last_error_msg()`](https://php.net/json_last_error_msg); or pass the `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR` option to `json_decode` and it will throw an exception rather than returning `null`.

If you do, you will find that it is complaining about invalid JSON: in JSON, all keys have to be quoted, and trailing commas aren't allowed at the end of lists.

It looks like someone's tried to write the JSON by hand, or just pasted some JavaScript code, which is not the same thing as JSON. They need to use a proper JSON serializer (e.g. [`JSON.stringify` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)).